# Как удалить элемент со страницы CefSharp.ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, cefsharp

Есть такой код браузера:

```
private ChromiumWebBrowser game_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница");
splitter_tlp.Controls.Add(game_browser, 0, 0);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы отображалась страница Википедии **без поиска**. Используется библиотека *CefSharp* и её элемент *ChromiumWebBrowser*. Всё стоит на WinForms (.NEW Framework 6.0).

Comment: Напишите JS скрипт, который это делает и выполните его.